# Limit cpu consumption PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jenkins, cpu-usage

I'm trying to set up a webserice for mobile that allows user to send and receive data from it.
Everything is PHP/MYSQL.

From time to time on that server, I've set up Jenkins to run a few php scripts that calculate various stuff that are quite intensive and may take up to 20 minutes to finish (They have to connnect to another website and check with an api).

Is there a way to limit the memory and cpu consumption (maybe even hdd - due to mysql) of a php script so the users don't experience slowdowns?

Or perhaps the system shouldn't be set up like this but rather a master-master mysql database and the scripts run on the second computer that isn't accessed by the users? (Also for this case wouldn't the second computer be slowed down thus the master-master connection would suffer?).

Is there any other way to set this?

A few other things to take into consideration:
- The data the script needs is sent by users. (It's read once at the beginning of the script, data that comes after is used next time).
- The script runs every hour or every 4 hours or once a day (multiple scripts).

Comment: How are you calling the PHP script from Jenkins ?  Using a shell step, or with some other type of build step ?